# Why can't I select this face?

Tags: modeling

I want to detach this polygon from the edge where the point is connected (illustrated below in Example A).

I've attempted to create a new polygon face by creating two points along the two edges of the polygon I want to disconnect, and then connecting them together with an edge (Example B).  The idea is that I can then select the new polygon and delete it, disconnecting the geometry in that area.

But Blender doesn't let me select the new polygon face for some reason, only the original polygon (Example C).

I'm very confused and would love a little help.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/03lgdcgjyb2nd0j/Vertice%20and%20Edge%20Help.blend?dl=0)

TL,DR: I am trying to disconnect a polygon connected to another at one point. My method doesn't work and I would like to know why.

BONUS QUESTION: Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

EXAMPLE A:
[image]

EXAMPLE B:
[image]

EXAMPLE C:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edge I've selected doesn't cut the face, it overlaps it, you've probably used the <kbd>F</kbd> function (fill) instead of <kbd>J</kbd> (join), which has created an edge over the existing face instead of cutting it off in two halves. To fix your problme, delete the edge with an <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Edges* and recreate one with <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Ha, it was that simple!  And yes I used F, didn't even think about using J.  Thank you ;)